# How can I display PostgreSQL database in Docker container?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, docker

I have both Django project and PotgreSQL database in Docker container. My question is how can I display my database? I was trying `docker exec -ti myproject_django_1 /bin/bash` and `docker exec -ti myproject_db_1 /bin/bash` but in both cases I can't use `psql` because of `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist` or `bash: psql: command not found`

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  db:
    image: postgres
  django:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - redis
  angular:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - django
```

**SOLUTION:**

`docker exec -it [DB_CONTAINER_ID] psql -U [USERNAME]`

Comment: Post your compose file in question

Comment: @TarunLalwani done.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the correct way, just change the user when you are inside the container:

```
docker exec -ti myproject_db_1 /bin/bash

su - postgres
psql
```